# What is the connection between fat tailedness of student t distribution and sparsity inducement in lower dimensions in context of t-sne

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, dimensionality-reduction, tsne, fat-tails

I have read that the t distribution is a heavy tailed distribution in comparison to Normal distribution. Also some say that heavy tailed distributions help in creating more sparsity.

My question is how does t distribution in t-SNE help in maintaining the distance between data points from a higher dimension to lower dimension. What exactly is the intuition behind using t distribution ?